# Why does my Gmail “drafts” folder have an unread count?

Tags: gmail

Obviously, it's a draft, therefore I've read it!

This is annoying as I use drafts to record a “follow up note” against an email received (but not replied to as there is no way of adding notes to emails in Gmail).

Anyone know how to stop it showing this?

Also odd is the fact that *Drafts* and *Sent mail* do not seem to conform to the labels model of Gmail.

I.e. there aren't really any folders as such, you are just seeing views of labels in the *All mail* folder.

Comment: Drafts and Sent Mail does conform to the labels method of Gmail, they are just views of All Mail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The count helps you to keep track of how many drafts you have, which is a number most people care about.

You can either

1. Hide Unread Counts (from settings-labs) but unfortunately, this applies to everything, not just draft
2. Use [GreasyMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) (but you'll have to create your script, I don't believe anybody has already such a problem)
3. Fix the problem in the first place: these are not email drafts that you might send one day, but notes from yourself to yourself, right? Then, send those drafts to yourself as emails! (and possibly star or label them accordingly). They will remain neatly threaded as with the rest of the conversation

Comment: send them to myself! d'oh! wood....trees.....
i like the cut of your jib, cowboy!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the built-in task manager instead of saving drafts. You can find it below the 'contacts'-button on the left, which is under your labels.
You can even create tasks based on the emails you receive, by choosing **More actions** > **Add to Tasks**.

Comment: I didn't even know/notice you could do this! waah!

It's the little things people miss..my latest discovery 'triple click select text block' in chrome/FF

The one other people never know about: middle click: opens links in a new tab; closes current tab you're hovering over

Comment: new
line
break
blah blah
blah

Comment: hmm that doesn't work .. :D